# Print lines with constraint in Python

Tags: python

Suppose we have the following text file with column `a` and column `b`:

```
D000001 T109
D000001 T195
D000002 T115
D000002 T131
D000003 T073
D000004 T170
```

I wonder how to produce the following structure:

```
D000001 T109 T195
D000002 T115 T131
D000003 T073
D000004 T170
```

Pasted below is initial skeleton in Python.

```
from __future__ import print_function

with open('descr2semtype_short.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        a, b = line.split()
        print(a + ' ' + b)
```

Comment: I am not the one who down voted but it may be due to the way you asked the question since print can not do clustering

Comment: You can use a dict, with `a` being the key, and `b` being appended to a list if the key already exists in the dict, or `mydict[a] = [b]` when the key does not exist. For which you can use either defaultdict` or `dict.setdefault()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of printing them there, you can keep a dictionary of the lines , with the first element of the line as the key and the second element as value (as a list , so that if another element comes for same key you can append to it).

And then print them at the end.

Example -

```
from __future__ import print_function

d = {}
with open('descr2semtype_short.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        a, b = line.split()
        if a not in d:
            d[a] = []
        d[a].append(b)

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print(k + ' ' + ' '.join(v))
```

From Python 2.7 onwards, If the order of the lines is important, then instead of `Dictionary` , we can use `OrderedDict` .

Example -

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
with open('descr2semtype_short.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        a, b = line.split()
        if a not in d:
            d[a] = []
        d[a].append(b)

for k,v in d.items():
    print(k + ' ' + ' '.join(v))
```

Comment: If the order is important , we can use OrderedDict.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools, operator
with open('descr2semtype_short.txt') as f:
    for key, items in itertools.groupby(
        (line.rstrip().split(None,1) for line in f),
        operator.itemgetter(0)):
        print(key, ' '.join(item[1] for item in items))
```

which gives the desired output:

```
D000001 T109 T195
D000002 T115 T131
D000003 T073
D000004 T170
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with [OrderedDic](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict)t , this way:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
with open('1.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        a,b = line.strip().split()
        print a,b
        if a not in d:
            d[a] = [b]
        else:
            d[a].append(b)
print d
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('D000001', ['T109', 'T109', 'T195']), ('D000002', ['T115', 'T115', 'T131']), ('D000003', ['T073', 'T073']), ('D000004', ['T170', 'T170', 'T175', 'T180'])])
```